# video upside down and flickering when resuming from sleep

Tags: suspend, video

I have Ubuntu 22.04, KDE, a GeForce RTX 3080, and 2 monitors (Asus VE278 and VE276). When I resume the computer from sleep mode, the video on the VE278 is upside down, and the video on both screens flickers really bad and there are squares and lines on both monitors. If I press Alt-Tab, it fixes itself and the video is normal.

What would cause this? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Here is the video information:

```
    $ sudo lshw -c video
    *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 12GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:191 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:4050000000-405fffffff memory:4060000000-4061ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

Comment: I found a possible workaround. I found that if I use the "Minimize All Windows" widget before I put it into sleep mode, when I bring it out the crazy video issues don't happen. It seems that it has a problem restoring visible windows back how they were when coming out of sleep, but if they're all minimized it doesn't cause a problem.